# How to map a modulation on a simple key-button in Ableton Live 9

Tags: modulation, ableton

I have modulation of a filter to cut the bass, so the bass is fading in 3 seconds.
Can I map this modulation to a keyboard to run that modulation only when I press mapped key, or to turn modulation on/off?
I don't have knobs, so I'm trying to fake them for live sessions. Becouse with a PC mouse it's impossible to mix in live without cutting the low and high frequencies, and use sends, all in one time.

thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can send the bass track into another track containing the filter.

On receiving track, you can create a session clip with automation for your filter sweep (under Clip view > Envelope view (third window) > (select desired effect) > Draw the sweep over bars.

Then you can trigger the clip with a key. (there are various modes for triggering the clip)

The reason for two tracks routed into one is that you can't play two clips on one channel at the same time, and you most likely want a separate control of the filter sweep.

To turn it on and off, create two additional clips, with full flat, or zeroed out filter, but you can also map the on/off button for the effect in recent versions of Live.